# Changing scrollbar size in Internet explorer 6 by using Windows CE 6.0

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6, windows-ce, scrollbar

I need to change the scroll bar's size of Internet Explorer 6 in Windows CE application. by referring to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa452005.aspx , I'm only able to change the scroll bar slider's size(by changing SBSizeV and SBSizeH value) but not the arrow button's size. Is there any way that I could change the size? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there is no reasonable way to do this.

You can change the size of a the scroll bars in a div.  See this question:

[Can you change the width of a scroll bar (scrolling DIV) in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259126/can-you-change-the-width-of-a-scroll-bar-scrolling-div-in-ie7)

That will ONLY work in IE and will make any other browser render the page very poorly.

Really, that's about as close as you can get.  The scroll bar is what the user agent (browser) uses to control overflowed content.  It's not something that is meant to be controlled by a web page at all.

IE lets you change the style of the scroll bar, its colors and such.  That's more control than other browsers will give you.

Sorry, but it's true.

Comment: Maybe not... http://www.bing.com/maps/ has no scroll bars by default.  I have no idea how.